# Java Swing GridLayout with big panel on top and bottom

Tags: java, swing, jpanel, layout-manager

[image]

I am trying to make this layout in Java swing. It is a 3x3 grid layout in the middle, with an upper panel and a lower panel on the bottom.

Comment: You will want to nest JPanels, each using its own layout manager to create your GUI. The outer JPanel uses BorderLayout (or use the JFrame's contentPane which already uses this), and the inner JPanel, the one placed BorderLayout.CENTER in the outer one uses GridLayout.

Answer (score 3):

By default a `JFrame` uses a `BorderLayout`. You can take advantage of the `BorderLayout` with code like:

```
frame.add(topPanel. BorderLayout.PAGE_START);
frame.add(gridPanel, BorderLayout.CENTER);
frame.add(bottomPanel, BorderLayout.PAGE_END);
```

Read the section from the Swing tutorial on [Using Layout Managers](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/layout/visual.html) for more information and working examples.

Keep a link to the tutorial handy for Swing Basics.